# Is perl sort better than Oracle sort?

Tags: oracle, perl, sorting, sql-order-by

If a query with ORDER BY in Oracle takes 10 times as many buffers as the query without ORDER BY, is it safe to assume that i should leave the sorting to the business layer (perl's sort) ?

Comment: You might take the decision to move a sort into business layer for *scaling* reasons rather than performance (more CPU/RAM in the business layer is often cheaper to arrange, assuming your code is built to scale). But only if this particular query is high impact enough to have you figuring out what fits your architecture best.

Comment: Consider [explain plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) for your sort query.

Answer (score 7):

All else being equal, I'd go with the Oracle sort.  With the right indexes, this should be much more efficient.

The only reason I'd wait to sort with Perl is if I needed to use the very latest version of a Unicode Collation, as Perl tends to track the Unicode standard a bit quicker than the folks at Oracle.  `perlbrew` can also be used to non-destructively add more modern perl versions to your machine with far less pain than an Oracle upgrade.  This, of course, presumes that you are permitted to get a current version of Perl installed in your business layer...

Answer (score 4):

It is **very likely** that perl could be the faster sort engine.  A while back a website (http://onlyjob.blogspot.com/2011/03/perl5-python-ruby-php-c-c-lua-tcl.html) posted a benchmark comparison of various languages. Even though perl is written in C it came out faster than C in certain tests.

[image: http://sites.google.com/site/onlyjob/arena/speed_close.png]

If this is a query you are doing often you might want to consider having some sort of index or stored procedure perhaps made directly on oracle which might speed up the querying.  If you don't have much control over the Oracle Database, however, by all means use the ninja style of perl.

One of the main advantages to leaving things on the Oracle end is you can tune oracle to make your specific query faster, also you could in theory beef up or cluster your oracle server if your data set ends up growing.

Comment: From a standing start, Perl is indeed an impressive tool, but the ability to provide indexes to Oracle can give it a significant head start...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any logic why the business layer would perform a sort faster or slower than Oracle would do it. The business layer would need to sort and buffer as much as Oracle would need to. And specifying a single line "ORDER BY [column]" is probably far easier than any client side code.

Comment: The order by is on a field which is a result of a huge case..end clause.

Comment: Then everything I said still applies. But please put EVERYTHING in your question.